# Disk Drill shows recoverable data after Eraser performance

Tags: hard-drive, recovery

I used today Eraser (from here: https://eraser.heidi.ie) to erase completely removed data from my SSD in computer (using Russian GOST method), but when I used Disk Drill after that, it still showed that some removed data had been found and they could be recovered. How it is possible?  I thought that after using Eraser there shouldn't be found any files apart from the existing ones. Btw just before running Disk Drill I removed from recycle bin some files to check if they could be recovered, but they hadn't been found. What may be the reason?

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: is this a hard drive or ssd?

Comment: @Keltari SSD, sorry, I've just corrected that.

Comment: the *only* way to properly erase a SSD is using the manufacturer's software.

Comment: Okay, but why did Disk Drill not find the files that I removed just before using it?

Comment: @Macios216 - Because the tool you used to wipe the drive was somewhat effective but as others hinted not totally effective on SSDs

Comment: @Ramhound I understand that Eraser doesn't work with SSD, but just before using Disk Drill that is used to recover data from either HDD or SSD I removed some files to check if I could recover them and they hadn't been found.

Comment: Okay, I think that I've found a solution. My SSD has a TRIM option enabled so that's why I couldn't find the files that had just been removed

Comment: But on the other hand, if I have the TRIM option enabled, why does Disk Drill show that some data are recoverable?

Comment: Your error description lacks details. One sentence is not enough to describe your configuration and the way you operated Heidi Eraser. As you can see, you have not gotten an answer yet. 
Be aware that I might not be able to answer your question even if you improved your question.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to properly erase a SSD is using the SSDs manufacturer's software.  Other methods might not work, due to wear leveling and over-provisioning.